# How to use ternary operation in reactjs when state contain a response from api call

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How to use ternary operation in reactjs when state contain a response from api call
whats goes wrong when i call a ternary operator inside react jsx 
apiResults state is storing response when api is called but there can be chance that there is no response or some error message  like network message so i was using a ternery conding but it fails

```js
<Modal.Body>
    {apiResults} ? <p>{apiResults.response}</p>  : <p>Network Signal Issue Please Try Again</p>
</Modal.Body>
```

Error:

```
index.js:1406 Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {response}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use your ternary operation in the `p` tag. Like below:

```
<Modal.Body>
    <p>{apiResults ? apiResults.response : 'Network Signal Issue Please Try Again'}</p>
</Modal.Body>
```